# Do not allow user to click on one of the tabs

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have 7 dates tabs in my screen. However, if the date falls on another month, I do not allow user to click on that tabs. I want to make them visible but not clickable.

[image: This is how the tabs look like]

This is part of my code:

```
public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, ArrayList<String> id, ArrayList<String> tasks,
                           ArrayList<Double> mondayHours, ArrayList<Double> tuesdayHours,
                           ArrayList<Double> wednesdayHours, ArrayList<Double> thursdayHours,
                           ArrayList<Double> fridayHours, ArrayList<Double> saturdayHours,
                           ArrayList<Double> sundayHours) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArrayList(EXTRA_CHECKED_TASK_ID, id);
    bundle.putStringArrayList(EXTRA_CHECKED_TASKS, tasks);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_MONDAY, mondayHours);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_TUESDAY, tuesdayHours);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_WEDNESDAY, wednesdayHours);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_THURSDAY, thursdayHours);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_FRIDAY, fridayHours);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_SATURDAY, saturdayHours);
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_SUNDAY, sundayHours);

    final String MON = "MON" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(0);
    final String TUE = "TUE" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(1);
    final String WED = "WED" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(2);
    final String THU = "THU" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(3);
    final String FRI = "FRI" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(4);
    final String SAT = "SAT" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(5);
    final String SUN = "SUN" + "\n" + MainActivity.sevenDatesList.get(6);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), bundle);
    adapter.addFragment(new MondayFragment(), MON);
    adapter.addFragment(new TuesdayFragment(), TUE);
    adapter.addFragment(new WednesdayFragment(), WED);
    adapter.addFragment(new ThursdayFragment(), THU);
    adapter.addFragment(new FridayFragment(), FRI);
    adapter.addFragment(new SaturdayFragment(), SAT);
    adapter.addFragment(new SundayFragment(), SUN);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ada.foresight.TimesheetActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblWeekMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/week"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblWeekNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/lblWeekMsg"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lblWeekMsg"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="fill" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I researched on similar problem, but we using different approach to create tabs and some I do not understand. [Research 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549951/how-do-i-disable-the-tab-click-event-for-a-pagertabstrip)

Comment: I've filed an issue (feature request) for this - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1020

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this what i do when to enable or disable tab or customize tab.

```
//get tab view
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tab_event.getChildAt(0);
//get number of tab
int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
//loop the tab
for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
    //get view of selected tab
    ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);

    if(j==DESIRED_POSITION){
         //disable the selected tab
         vgTab.setEnable(false);
    }       
}
```

if you attach with viewpager, you need to disable the swipe of the viewpager. If not, you still can swipe to the disable tab.

Comment: is tab_event a tabLayout?

Comment: yes.its Tablayout. `protected TabLayout tab_event = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs)`;

Comment: why do you need cycle if you want to disable only one position?

Comment: it just a sample.. you can just put fix position if you want.. :)

Comment: Hello @ZeroOne, I have a Que. how can I disable parallel click of tabItem? For Instance: My app has been crashed When I click on two TabItem Parallel. Can you give me Ans?, How can I fix It.

Answer (score 8):

Just improved answer of @ZeroOne:

```
private void disableTab(int tabNumber)
    {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(tabNumber);
        vgTab.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: Hello @yozhik, I have a Que. how can I disable parallel click of tabItem?

For Instance: My app has been crashed When I click on two TabItem Parallel. Can you give me Ans?, How can I fix It.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `TabLayout` class and override

```
void selectTab(final Tab tab, boolean updateIndicator)
```

method, like this:

```
@Override
void selectTab(final Tab tab, boolean updateIndicator){
    if (tab.getPosition() == <selectable_position>){
      super.selectTab(tab, updateIndicator)
    }
}
```

However, you should aware that this logic will also disable swiping to that tabs via `ViewPager`.

See [source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.java#L1728) for more details.